# sonarqube 5.0 giving Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object message

Tags: java, oracle, hudson, sonarqube-5.0

I am trying to use SonarQube 5.0 with Hudson 3.2.1.
Sonar runner version 2.4.
Once Hudson invokes a sonar analysis, it ends with a build failure. 
SonarQube is configured with Oracle 12c database using ojdbc7.jar driver.

The log output -

```
[workspace] $ /opt/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/URL id pass -Dsonar.host.url=http://host:port id pass -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/basedir -Dsonar.projectName=prjName -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=org:prj -Dsonar.sources=.

SonarQube Runner 2.4

Java 1.7.0_75 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)

Linux 2.6.18-308.el5 amd64

INFO: Runner configuration file: /opt/sonar-runner-2.4/conf/sonar-runner.properties

INFO: Project configuration file: NONE

INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)

INFO: Work directory: /basedir

INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0

04:04:54.792 INFO  - Load global referentials...

04:04:55.100 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 311 ms

04:04:55.105 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/hudson/.sonar/cache

04:04:55.116 INFO  - Install plugins

04:04:55.196 INFO  - Install JDBC driver

04:04:55.205 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbcURL

04:04:59.095 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate

04:05:01.906 INFO  - Load project referentials...

04:05:02.242 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 336 ms

04:05:02.242 INFO  - Load project settings

04:05:02.594 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...

04:05:02.616 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 21 ms

04:05:02.622 INFO  - Apply project exclusions

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total time: 9.050s

Final Memory: 16M/242M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar

ERROR: Caused by: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

ERROR: 

ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.

ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Finished: FAILURE
```

I have replaced the actual parameters like host,port, jdbcurl with placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you are running Oracle 12c version 12.1.0.1.0 and using the JDBC drivers that came with it. The Oracle 12c JDBC driver that comes with 12.1.0.1.0 has a bug with the oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.initMetaDataColumnIndexes() method, which is now fixed with the 12.2.0 patch. I am guessing that your error "getting generated key" is related to this issue. You should enable logging within SonarQube so that you can verify the root cause.

Full post is [here](http://glennpaulley.ca/conestoga/2015/06/configuring-sonarqube-with-oracle-12c/).